# How to extract the closePrice only from the following json query?

Tags: javascript, json

This should be simple though it's giving me fits.
I simply want to pull out the most recent closePrice from https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=LUV but I can't get the correct syntax. Ideas?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $.getJSON("https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=LUV", function(data){
            $("#LUVPrice").text(data["closePrice"].toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```js
fetch('https://accounts.hive-engine.com/marketHistory?symbol=LUV')  
 .then((res) => res.json())  
 .then((data) => {
var d=parseFloat(data[0].closePrice).toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("LUVPrice").innerText=d
    })
```

```html
<div id="LUVPrice"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I was close to getting it right, but this really helps. The line (data[0].closePrice).toFixed(2) was what I needed. By the way, if you are on the Hive blockchain, let me know a username and I'll give you some LUV tokens. :)

Comment: No sir I don't have Hive. If this answer helped then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: The suggestion by Sourabh was all that it took to fix the snag. Much appreicated.